# How do I realign filtered cards after search?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

After I search "card two" I would like the results to realign to display from the beginning of the results section.

Also I cannot find any documentation on how to paginate cards...I just want to clarify paginate cards. I can find documentation on how to paginate tables. The ones on cards are not using the card class.

I have tried using the card-deck class instead of the card-block class. Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/NWKGagz

```
<!-- search bar -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="myFilter" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search by MBTI personality type..">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- results -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="myItems">
    <!-- card one -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card one</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card two -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card two</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card three -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card three</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card four -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card four</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, title, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
    cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-block h5.card-title");
        if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            cards[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            cards[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I expect after I type "card two" for the results to reformat and the card two to replace the card ones initial position.

Pagination...I would like to display 12 cards on 1 page then 12 on the next page and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the parent element like follows

```
if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    cards[i].parentElement.style.display = "flex"
} else {
    cards[i].parentElement.style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: This is perfect mkHun. I'll keep searching around for pagination documentation with cards but thanks for the help